# Sum cell values below until blank cell

Tags: excel-formula

I need the excel formula to add the cell values until blank cell.
I have tried with the below formula :

```
=IF(A4="",SUM(A4:INDEX(A$1:$A4,MATCH(TRUE,(A$1:$A4=""),A4))),A4)
```

But it shows the wrong result.

Please see the picture below to understand, what kind of result I am searching for.
[image: what i am searching for]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With blocks of data in column **A**, in **B2** enter:

```
=IF(A2="",SUM($A$1:A2)-SUM($B$1:B1),"")
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

Each value in column **B** is the sum of the **A**-block above it.
Using column **B** allows us to avoid having to figure out where in column **A** to put a *SUM()* formula.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result on the same column, give a try with this macro,

```
Sub total()
Dim i As Long, temp As Long
For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    If Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
        temp = temp + Cells(i, 1)
    Else
        Cells(i, 1) = temp
        temp = 0
        Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. :)
This Macro is work perfectly. But I need the output using excel formulas
Can you please help me out for this :)

Comment: Formulas cannot help you out if it is the same column. May be the accepted answer is the only way out

Comment: Thanks. Need one more help.

I want to apply this macro for entire column and whenever I put the value in Column A it will automatically add values below.

Comment: @Dheeraj Looks like its a different question from this one. Since the answer is already accepted with this question, please post a new one with required data in it. We will take a look and help you out !!